# ValueError: subsurface rectangle outside surface area

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making an platformer game where the camera follows the player. I'm trying to implement this by having a large surface surface with the whole map and only blitting a zoomed in section. however im only getting 30 fps (minimized) and 8 fps (full screen).

So my attempt to optimize it was to to crop it before blitting but i get `ValueError: subsurface rectangle outside surface area`

code

```py
class screen_handler:
    def __init__(self, screen=False, mapSize=[3, 3]):
        if not screen:  # if screen isn't open
            init()  # initialize pygame
            user32 = ctypes.windll.user32  # set user32
            os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (user32.GetSystemMetrics(0) / 4, user32.GetSystemMetrics(1) / 4)  # center future screen
            screen = display.set_mode((640, 512),  RESIZABLE)  # create screen

        self.screen = screen  # save screen
        self.blit_surf = Surface((640 * mapSize[0], 512 * mapSize[1]))  # create blit_surf
        self.clock = time.Clock() # create clock
        self.neutralizerZoom = min(self.blit_surf.get_width() / 640, self.blit_surf.get_height() / 512)  # reset zoom

        self.zoom = 2
        self.mousePos = [0, 0]
        self.cameraPos = [0, 0]

        self.fit_to_rect = self.blit_surf.get_rect().fit(self.screen.get_rect())  # fit the surface to the screen
        self.fit_to_rect.size = self.fit_to_rect.width * self.neutralizerZoom * self.zoom, self.fit_to_rect.height * self.neutralizerZoom * self.zoom  # add zoom



    def video_resize(self):
        self.fit_to_rect = self.blit_surf.get_rect().fit(self.screen.get_rect())  # fit the surface to the screen
        self.fit_to_rect.size = self.fit_to_rect.width * self.neutralizerZoom * self.zoom, self.fit_to_rect.height * self.neutralizerZoom * self.zoom  # add zoom

    def update(self):
        scaled = transform.scale(self.blit_surf, (self.fit_to_rect.width, self.fit_to_rect.height))  # scale surface to screen
        self.fit_to_rect.topleft = self.screen.get_rect().top + self.cameraPos[0], self.screen.get_rect().left + self.cameraPos[1]  # center surface & camera pos

        self.mousePos[0] = (mouse.get_pos()[0] / (scaled.get_width() / self.blit_surf.get_width())) - (self.cameraPos[0] / (scaled.get_width() / self.blit_surf.get_width()))  # scale x axis mouse pos
        self.mousePos[1] = (mouse.get_pos()[1] / (scaled.get_height() / self.blit_surf.get_height()))  # scale y axis mouse pos
        scaled = scaled.subsurface(self.fit_to_rect.x, self.fit_to_rect.y, self.fit_to_rect.x + self.fit_to_rect.width, self.fit_to_rect.y + self.fit_to_rect.height)
        self.screen.blit(scaled ,(0, 0))  # blit surface to screen
        #self.screen.blit(scaled, self.fit_to_rect)
        display.flip()  # update screen
        self.clock.tick(60)
        print(self.clock.get_fps())
```

note: please tell me if there is a better way/ quicker way of implementing a camera

Comment: At what line was the error raised?

Comment: @atanay line 33 - scaled = scaled.subsurface(self.fit_to_rect)

Comment: I think the problem is that the rectangle you are passing at the subsurface function is of the form (x,y,width,height) and not (x,y,x+width,y+height). a way to check that is by printing self.fit_to_rect and checking for yourself

Comment: so like this? (edited code)

Comment: try to run it, and we will see :)

Comment: nope, it still has the same message...

Comment: the same message at the same line? also, like I said, print the parameters before you call the function, so you can see if they make sense

Comment: yes and yes, however i noticed if i set x and y to 0 it works but both positive or negative 1 will produce the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i do my camera movement:

```py
WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = ...
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), RESIZABLE)
screen = pygame.Surface(your_resolution)
...
scroll_x, scroll_y = player_position  # get the scroll
...
screen.blit(image, (x_pos + scroll_x, y_pos + scroll_y))
...
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
        WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.size
...
window.blit(pygame.transform.scale(screen, (WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)), (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
```

every time you want to show something you need to blit it onto screen instead of window.

if you want to have the same scale i would recommend the follwing class:

```py
class Window:
    def __init__(self, surf, width, height):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), RESIZABLE)
        self.surf = surf
        self.orig_w, self.orig_h = surf.get_size()
        self.set_sizes(width, height)

    def set_sizes(self, width, height):
        self.rate = min(width / self.orig_w, height / self.orig_h)
        self.width = int(self.orig_w * self.rate)
        self.x_off = int((width - self.width) / 2)
        self.height = int(self.orig_h * self.rate)
        self.y_off = int((height - self.height) / 2)

    def get_mouse_pos(self):
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        return int((mouse_x - self.x_off) / self.rate), int((mouse_y - self.y_off) / self.rate)

    def show(self):
        self.screen.fill((50, 50, 50))
        self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.surf, (self.width, self.height)), (self.x_off, self.y_off))
        pygame.display.flip()
```

EDIT: OPTIMTZING

the following code will replace the line that caused you problems:
instead of

```py
scaled = scaled.subsurface(...)
self.screen.blit(scaled, (0, 0))
```

do

```py
self.screen.blit(scaled, (0, 0), self.fit_to_rect)
```

this is more efficient because it doesn't need to create the subsurface but blits is directly onto the screen.
optimizing tips:
avoid recreating surfaces every frame.
your large surface does only need to be created when the map is loaded and never again. if you are rotating images you can simply create a list or dict of rotated images at the start of the program and just need to call it. same goes for changes in scale.

use `img = img.convert()`
this is a pretty simple optimizing trick.

Comment: i did try doing something like that however im getting only 8fps

Comment: If the performance is low you should consider OPTIMIZING. you are mentioning a big surface that contains the whole level. (this surface doesn't need to be recreated every frame) you can select which part of this giant surface you want to blit by using the 3rd area argument. i will edit my answer to include different optimizings

Comment: @lukan i added the optimizations and also included a possible fix. i'd appreciate if you would check if this helps.

Comment: thank you so much, how i update the character if i dont blit the map every frame?

Comment: You still have to _blit_ it every frame. the thing you could optimize is _creating_ or _copying_ the surface (i don't know how you load your maps and do physics and stuff, if you could provide more details about that i could (hopefully) give a solution that is fitting in your case.)